# Disk read error. click Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart. Windows 7, Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-7

I have Windows 7 on my system and recently I installed Ubuntu 12.10 as dual boot, both worked fine.

One day I created some shortcuts to Windows folders in Ubuntu. After that, when I am logging in to Ubuntu. I get the following error message and I am unable to boot to Ubuntu.

Please can you help me find my bootsector info?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5988981/

Comment: I tried downloading boot repair tool and tried restore MBR option, Here is the new link to boot info  http://paste.ubuntu.com/5989058/

Comment: Whats the error message that you are getting when you are logging in? or do you mean when you choose Ubuntu from the Grub menu?

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows partition was a dyanamic disk,

as described from your [*earlier* pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5988981/):

> =================== Advice displayed in case of recommended repair
>
> SFS detected. You may want to retry after converting Windows dynamic >partitioning (SFS partitions) to a basic disk. This can be performed via tools >such as TestDisk or EASEUS-Partition-Master / MiniTool-Partition-Wizard.
>   Do you want to continue?
>
> =================== Default settings
>
> Recommended-Repair This setting would reinstall the grub2 of sda3 into
>   the MBR of sda. Additional repair would be performed:
>   unhide-bootmenu-10s

I think the problem was corrected, but to be sure look in windows, in your startbar, type

```
diskmgmt.msc
```

to **open up disk management
and check whether your disk is listed as dyanamic or basic.**

You can take help from this link about it- http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html

After your [*second* boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5988981/)

> Recommended-Repair This setting would reinstall the grub2 of sda3 into
>   the MBR of sda. Additional repair would be performed:
>   unhide-bootmenu-10s

Grub seems to have been successfully installed.

> Boot successfully repaired.
>   You can now reboot your computer.

So check about the Basic Disk/Dyanamic Disk part, and tell us more completely whetever problem you are facing.